# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl data from the URL below and I keep getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

How do I crawl the website so it loops through every td and gets the bilingual text?

Here is what I have so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars/"

html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table-translations"})
gdp_table_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("tr")  # contains # rows

# Get all the headings of Lists
headings = []
for td in gdp_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    # remove any newlines and extra spaces from left and right
    headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? Do you have a backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

you have kept td.b inside for loop which is giving error because in the table there is nothing with 'b' as an attribute. By removing it you can get output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars/"

html_content = requests.get(url).text
# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table-translations"})
gdp_table_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("tr")  # contains # rows

# Get all the headings of Lists
headings = []
for td in gdp_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    # remove any newlines and extra spaces from left and right
    headings.append(td.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

Here is the output I got

```
['No.', 'Mongolian text', 'Loosely translated into English']
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line `headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())` as there is no `b` attribute in table's column the program is throwing error.

Moreover, you don't need to parse `strong` text seperately, use `td.text` instead.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars/"

html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table-translations"})
gdp_table_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("tr")  # contains # rows
print(gdp_table_data[0].find_all("td"))
# Get all the headings of Lists
headings = []
for td in gdp_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    # remove any newlines and extra spaces from left and right and append to headings
    headings.append(td.get_text(strip=True))
print(headings)
# output ['No.', 'Mongolian text', 'Loosely translated into English']
```